# Запускаю процесс через exec. Как подождать, пока он выполнится?

Tags: java, cmd

Запускаю разархивирование.

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c d:/time/pak/rar.exe x d:/time/pak/folder.rar d:/time/1");
```

Архивирование  длится около минуты.
После него нужно выполнять определенные действия.
Что можно делать, чтобы программа дальше не выполнялась, пока выполняется процесс.

Thread.sleep() не помогает.
Этот метод останавливает и архивирование тоже.
Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 60 localhost"); тоже самое, останавливает извлечение архива.

```
proc1.waitFor(); не работает
```

Если написать

```
rocess proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait d:/time/pak/rar.exe x d:/time/pak/folder.rar d:/time/1");
```

то proc1.waitFor(); работает, но появляется консоль.

Comment: А так `"cmd /c /wait d:/time/pak/rar.exe x d:/time/pak/folder.rar d:/time/1"`?

Comment: Так не работает. Оставлю с консолью пока.

Answer (score 1):

`Process.waitFor` ждёт завершения запущенного процесса. Он работает и возвращается как только запущенный процесс завершается. Дело в том что Вы запускаете два процесса - cmd и rar, причем cmd запускает rar и завершается (вариант без /wait).
Судя по комментариям Вас не совсем устраивает факт появления консоли от cmd. Тогда возникает вопрос, а зачем вообще запускать cmd? Почему бы не запускать сразу rar?

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("d:/time/pak/rar.exe x d:/time/pak/folder.rar d:/time/1");
```

если все же cmd и start нужны, то start может запускать без консоли с опцией **/b** см: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start

еще можно попробовать запускать через start но без cmd

Comment: Я с этого и начинал. Запускается разархивирование, могу следить в totale сколько файлов появляется, и после определенного числа файлов, или размера, разархивирование прекращается. Если выполнение завершить в eclipse, то остальные файлы появляются.

Comment: попробуйте запускать через ProcesBuilder и редиректить вывод, может там ошбика у рара какая то возникает, а может после определенного количества файлов в папке коммандер перестает авторефрешить.